# Jmeter - Ramp Up Time vs Constant Timer

Tags: java, testing, performance-testing, web-api-testing, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to create a scenario where I need to hit an API with 200 unique hits(in my case 200 loan numbers).

I need 10 hits at a time for every 5 seconds

I used below values to generate above scenario

> Threads: 200
> Ramp UP: 300
> Loop: 1
>
> Synchronizing timer::
> Number of simulated Users to Group by: 10
>
> Constant Timer ::
> Thread Delay (in milliseconds): 5000

even after giving 5000 milliseconds in constant timer, I am getting 10 hits for every 15 seconds. can someone help me how to get 10 hits at a time for every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you have 200 threads and 300 seconds ramp-up time it means that JMeter will start 200 threads in 300 seconds. So you will get 10 threads up and running **only by 19th second**. You need to decrease your ramp-up time to `100` in order to be able to hit first request with 10 users.
2. Given you have Loop Count set to `1` JMeter will shut down threads which have already finished their work, I would recommend setting it to `-1` so threads will loop forever. You can limit your test duration to desired via "Scheduler" section of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller). See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for more detailed explanation.
3. I would also suggest replacing your Constant Timer with the [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler so all your threads would be at the same page.